# Where shall I start in making a scraper or a bot using python?

Tags: python, cgi

I'm not that new in programming languages(python) but I got no clue on where will I start in making a bot or a scraper using python?. should I study in cgi programming? or does the scraper runs just using a python script? Should I build a server for that? Got no clue for this... thanks for the help

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Well, I suppose so, only because the OP never accepted an answer and hasn't been around since then, so it's been hanging around as “open” ever since.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some links to get you started.

- [Build a basic web scraper in Python](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/build-a-basic-web-scraper-in-python/)
- [Scrapy: An open source web scraping framework for Python](http://scrapy.org/)
- [Web scraping with Python. Part 1: Crawling](http://www.akasig.org/2004/12/29/web-scraping-with-python-part-1-crawling/)

Answer (score 2):

If you’re trying to access websites that make heavy use of JavaScript, you might, overall, find [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) easier.

Selenium is a server that controls actual web browsers on your server, and a client library (including a Python port) that allows you to control the browsers and inspect the pages in them.

It’s definitely more overhead up-front to configure (and figure out) the server and client library (and to make sure you have a working browser on your system), but if the website does a lot of stuff in JavaScript, your actual scraping code could be a lot less hairy.

Answer (score 1):

Screen scraping involves a lot of regular expressions to get the exact data you want. You also want to know what sort of data you want to analyze and how you want to store it.

To get the pages, you'll need to utilize libraries such as urllib (or urllib2) and regular expressions (re) or a good script to use is beautifulsoup to do your dirty work (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

If you want to build a pure bot that does what the search engines do, you also have to build a smart enough bot to know that you don't keep pinging the same domain continuously (results in a DOS attack).