# How to write a Python robot that browses

Tags: python, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where shall I start in making a scraper or a bot using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075792/where-shall-i-start-in-making-a-scraper-or-a-bot-using-python)

I know it's obviously possible...
I was asked to implement some sort of robot that visits a website, logs in, visits a set of links, fills a search form with date inputs to get a XLS file and logs off.
If done manually this whole ordeal takes almost an hour, so a script/robot would save us a lot of time.

Ideas? Libraries? I guess I'm going to need urllib?
Or maybe not use Python at all?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I searched quite a bit for "python crawler" and didn't come upon Mechanize or Scrapy until right before the comments :/
I'll look further into Mechanize first. Thanks.

Comment: See [Where shall I start in making a scraper or a bot using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075792/where-shall-i-start-in-making-a-scraper-or-a-bot-using-python).

Comment: How about mechanize? http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: Even better is http://scrapy.org/

Comment: As @philip-southam said, use Scrapy is great for crawling web pages, so it would be no problem at this stage. However, there might be some anti-bot mechanisms(ex: CAPTCHA) along with the login forms, and this would be a problem for you to make a bot doing "log in and fetch some files" sort of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a fan of the [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) python module.  Here is a small sample of the code from it that I used not too long ago to do basic browsing and scraping.

```
import twill
import twill.commands as c

def login():
    c.clear_cookies()
    c.go('http://icfpcontest.org/icfp10/login')
    c.fv(1, 'j_username', 'Side Effects May Include...')
    c.fv(1, 'j_password', '<redacted>')
    c.submit()
    c.save_cookies('/tmp/icfp.cookie')

all_cars_rx = re.compile(r'<td style="width: 20%;">(\d+)</td><td>(\d+)</td>')
def list_cars():
    c.go('http://icfpcontest.org/icfp10/score/instanceTeamCount')
    cars = re.findall(all_cars_rx, c.show())
    if not cars:
        sys.stderr.write(c.show())
        sys.stderr.write('Could not find any cars')
    return cars;
```

It is worth mentioning that one should **not** use a regular expression to parse HTML.  What you have here is a dirty hack that was done for the ICFP on a very short time table.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've discovered the [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) and used it for the similar task. It is the command line JavaScript interpreter with the fully functional Webkit engine built-in. IMHO, it is really easy-to-use tool for tasks like yours and you've got all sort of scriptable functionality you'd have say with Firebug. Also it has the built-in call for taking screenshots and saving them to image files.